# How to reliably get Iframe content body updates in react effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, iframe, react-hooks

I'm loading html into an iframe through srcDoc with the `sandbox="allow-same-origin"`.

I notice that `frameRef.contentDocument.body.innerHTML` is empty even though the content displays. I set an effect to watch that property and it is always undefined.

How can I reliably get the body of the iframe's content and be able to watch it for changes?

---

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-voice-ufp664

in the console if you do `refNode.contentDocument.body.innerHTML`, you get the correct output. But through react, it's undefined.

I tried setting effect hooks on specific properties like the innerHTML as well as the entire node object, no avail.

I tried using a regular ref, same results.

I expected to be able to get the body of the iframe and watch it for changes.

Comment: You have a typo: `innertHTML` -> `innerHTML` - `frameElement?.contentDocument?.body?.innerHTML.length`.

Comment: @OriDrori thanks for that catch! The issue still persists tho, innerHTML is empty/length 0 even tho the content has loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `onLoad` event of the `iframe` element to set the state when the when frame is ready.

[image: Edit confident-estrela-igmq8t]

Code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [frameElement, setFrameElement] = React.useState(null);
  const [templateHtml, setTemplateHtml] = React.useState(null);

  const handleFrameElement = React.useCallback(e => {
    setFrameElement(e.target);
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setTemplateHtml(html), 1200);
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      "HOOK ",
      frameElement?.contentDocument?.body?.innerHTML?.length
    );
  }, [frameElement]);

  return (
    <div>
      {templateHtml && (
        <iframe
          srcDoc={templateHtml}
          sandbox="allow-same-origin"
          onLoad={handleFrameElement}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```